# Increase Email Form Security! - Drag and drop to submit form?

Tags: jquery, html, email, spam-prevention

Imagine if you will a dilemma in which spam bots notoriously rule the world with inputting text box fields at random. One of my supposed solutions I found online was to input some sort of hidden text field to try and thwart the bots from spamming, others have made mathematical algorithms for people to fill (1+1=?). Doing a bit of thinking, and 68 spammed messaged from bots later, I had a sort of idea..

What if you could check the form via seeing if an images/divs/etc is dragged onto another image? For example.. For my form it could ask my viewers to drag an apple into a basket to prove that you're a human. Certainly spam bots have click events, but I think such an action would require highly elaborate code to perform automously. Thereby, making it difficult for them to successfully spam.

Even further, howabout the "basket" is always in a random position to ensure genuine responses and to slow bots further? I have no idea how this would be done out side of some current canvas/html5 tags, css, and potentially heavy javascript, but if it is possible how would this be done?? I understand if this cannot be done, but just was wondering, I hope I'm making sense here.

Comment: It would work but it sounds more eye-candy than good protection. I would prefer http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/asirra/

Comment: 3dvia's blog actually did use this method when it was active. I forget the name of it - now their comments section is closed so I'm afraid I can't give you a name. Maybe I could find it in my browser history though... EDIT: It was called Sweet Captcha (thanks Wayback Machine) http://sweetcaptcha.com/

Comment: Brilliant find tomyshadow!!! I didn't even know something like this already existed! Many thanks! I'll take a look into it.